# convert BLOB file into image MYSQL python

Tags: python, mysql

I used requests to get a the bytes of an image and then tried storing it in a MySQL table as a BLOB field; but when i try and get the blob file back and use pillow to get an image it throws and error saying a bytes-like-object is required not a tuple.

i know the bytes are correct because when i try and read the image first without putting it into the sql table it works fine.

```
import mysql.connector # imports sql functionality
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

r =requests.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/images/I/81VoHkKTTBL._AC_UY327_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg")

db = mysql.connector.Connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user1",
    passwd="paswd",
    database="temporary_database",
    )
cursor = db.cursor()
imag = r.content
cursor.execute("select img from test where Price_of_item = 21")

for x in cursor:
    img = x

image_data = img
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
image.show()
```

this code is when the bytes are passed to the sql as a BLOB and doesn't work

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uayhy.png)

```
import mysql.connector # imports sql functionality
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

r =requests.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/images/I/81VoHkKTTBL._AC_UY327_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg")
img = r.content

image_data = img
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
image.show()
```

this isn't passed to the sql table and works perfectly fine

Comment: how did you store the images

Comment: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (img) VALUES (%s,)", (r.content))

Comment: then try https://pynative.com/python-mysql-blob-insert-retrieve-file-image-as-a-blob-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part of your code:

```py
for x in cursor:
    img = x
```

Each row `x` in your cursor is a tuple, not a single value.

If your query was selecting more than one column from your table, the cursor would generate a tuple, with each element of this tuple containing one element for each column in the query.  The situation is no different if you are only selecting one column.  In this case, the cursor generates tuples with only one element in them.

There are a few possible ways to deal with this.  Firstly, you can just pick out the first element in the tuple:

```py
for row in cursor:
    img = row[0]
```

Alternatively, use a destructuring assignment in the loop body:

```py
for row in cursor:
    (img,) = row
```

or immediately destructure what comes out of the cursor:

```py
for (x,) in cursor:
    img = x
```